# BASH: echo -e does not work with Unicode Cyrillic

Tags: linux, bash, unicode, cyrillic

I recently switched to another working machive and faced a problem when I work with Cyrillic. My Bash script gets new messages from an application and works with them.

However the messages are mostly written in Cyrillic and I get results like "\u043f\u0440\u0438\u0432\u0456\u0442"

On my old system that run Ubuntu I could easily convert it to normal letters with `echo -e`

```
[18:18 deimos@nc ~] echo -e "\u043f\u0440\u0438\u0432\u0456\u0442"
привіт
```

Unfortunatelly that does not work with the new system on CentOS 6.

```
[15:21] [server1.nichan.net ~] # echo -e "\u043f\u0440\u0438\u0432\u0456\u0442"
\u043f\u0440\u0438\u0432\u0456\u0442
```

Both systems are on English. The CentOS one was installed just today so there is not much on it. The only thing I installed on it so far is pip and some Python modules my scripts require, so it's safe to say the system is fresh.

Also, other Unicode symbols seem to work just fine. The only issue is Cyrillic:

```
[15:21] [server1.nichan.net ~] # echo -e "\xE2\x98\xA0"
☠
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

UPD: It appears my Bash was outdated. I had 4.1 and this function requires at least 4.3. I updated Bash using this guide:

```
wget https://ftp.gnu.org/pub/gnu/bash/bash-4.3.tar.gz
tar xvfz bash-4.3.tar.gz
cd bash-4.3/
./configure
make
ls -la bash
cp -f bash /bin/bash
/bin/bash
```

Tributes to https://www.stevejenkins.com/blog/2014/09/how-to-manually-update-bash-to-patch-shellshock-bug-on-older-fedora-based-systems/

Comment: Which shell are you using? On my Ubuntu 17.04, /bin/echo -e does not expand \u<n> but built in echo does. What does "type -a echo" give?

Comment: Thank you, I figured it out. Updated the post.

Comment: CentOS 6 is nearly 6 years old; CentoOS 7 was release almost 3 years ago. `bash` 4.4 was released over 6 months ago.

Comment: As an aside, consider using `printf '%b\n' "..."` instead of `echo -e "..."` -- see the APPLICATION USAGE and RATIONALE sections of the [POSIX spec for `echo`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Support for `\Uxxxx` Unicode literals in the arguments to `echo` and `printf` were added in `bash` 4.2.

From the [change log](https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/CHANGES):

> This document details the changes between this version, bash-4.2-alpha,
>   and the previous version, bash-4.1-release.
>
> [...]
>
> 3. New Features in Bash
>
>    [...]
>
>    d.  $'...', echo, and printf understand \uXXXX and \UXXXXXXXX escape sequences.